# Controlling unification order in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a function whose second argument depends on its first argument, like this:

```
Definition is_nice (f : Formula) (pf : FProof f) : bool := true.
```

And I have a unification goal, like this

```
is_nice (some_formula ?u) (some_proof ?u) =^= is_nice f pf
```

.
which fails to unify when the unification starts from left to right,
but it would be unifiable when we first unify (`some_proof ?u =^= pf`),
infer the value for `u` during this unification, and then proceed to unify
`some_formula ?u =^= f` with the knowledge of `u`.

How do I make Coq solve such unification problem? I have the following ideas:

1. Change `is_nice` so that the order of parameters is different. However, I do not know how to achieve this because of the dependency between the parameters. We would need to somehow break this dependency...
2. Change `is_nice` so that it uses some canonical structure trickery to reorder the unification problems. There is some trick like that described in the extended version of Gonthier's 'How to make ad hoc proof automation less ad hoc' paper, but it does not seem to be directly applicable.
3. Somehow infer `?u` even before the unification of that goal starts. But again, I am not sure how.

I may use UniCoq, but it is not a requirement.

As an example, consider the following piece of code:

```
Inductive Formula : Set :=
| f_atomic : nat -> Formula
| f_imp : Formula -> Formula -> Formula.

Inductive FProof : Formula -> Set :=
| P1 : forall (f1 f2 : Formula), FProof (f_imp f1 (f_imp f2 f1))
| MP : forall (f1 f2 : Formula), FProof f1 -> FProof (f_imp f1 f2) -> FProof f2
.

Definition is_nice (f : Formula) (pf : FProof f) : bool := true.

Lemma impl_5_is_nice': forall (n1 : nat), is_nice _ (P1 (f_atomic (n1 + 0)) (f_atomic 5)) = true.
Proof. intros. unfold is_nice. reflexivity. Qed.


Lemma impl_3_5_is_nice: is_nice _ (P1 (f_atomic 3) (f_atomic 5) ) = true.
Proof. intros.
  Fail apply impl_5_is_nice'.
  apply (impl_5_is_nice' 3).
Qed.
```

The types `Formula` and `FProof` represent formulas and proofs in a deeply-embedded logic. The proof script of `Lemma impl_3_5_is_nice` demostrates the problem: the first `apply` does not go through, because the unification of `f_atomic (?n1 + 0)` with `f_atomic 3` fails. However, when we manually compare the goal and Lemma `impl_5_is_nice'`, we can realize that `n1` has to be `3`, and so we can specialize the lemma.

4. Another solution would be to inspect the goal using `match goal`, but then the problem is that I have quite a lot of lemmas similar `impl_5_is_nice'`, and the tactic that would do the inspection would need to understand each one of these lemmas. Ideally, this would be unified using type classes or canonical structures, but this is really a 'backup plan'.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding all the details of the question, but the problem of equipping lemmas or functions with extra arguments to cope with the fact unification proceeds in a certain order is already addressed in the mathematical component libraries, if I remember well.  I will try to collect more information, but maybe you can start exploring in that material.